# Black screen appears before the actual video on re-recording

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation, quicktime

I am recording a video in my app whose recording time is sent by the server. The server tests for certain gestures in the video and if it fails sends back a flag asking to re-record and resend.

Problem: Initial video is of correct duration. But the videos, in the event of server 'retry request' are appended with a black screen for a certain amount of time and then the recorded video plays.

flow:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // get recording time
    [self getRecordingData];
}
```

recording function:

```
-(void)startRecording {
    self.isRecording = YES;
    self.isProcessing = YES;
    [self startWritingToVideoFile];
    [self logicMethodToStopRecording];
}
```

writing to video file function:

```
-(void)startWritingToVideoFile{
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:640], AVVideoWidthKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt:480], AVVideoHeightKey, AVVideoCodecTypeH264, AVVideoCodecKey,nil];
    self.assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput  assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:outputSettings];
    [self.assetWriterInput setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( 90 * M_PI ) / 180 )];
    self.pixelBufferAdaptor =
    [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor alloc]
     initWithAssetWriterInput:self.assetWriterInput
     sourcePixelBufferAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA],
      kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
      nil]];
    
    self.videoPath = [Utilities pathForTemporaryFileWithSuffix:@"mov"];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.videoPath];
    /* Asset writer with MPEG4 format*/
    self.assetWriterMyData = [[AVAssetWriter alloc]
                              initWithURL: videoURL
                              fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
                              error:nil];
    [self.assetWriterMyData addInput:self.assetWriterInput];
    self.assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    [self.assetWriterMyData startWriting];
    [self.assetWriterMyData startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
    self.isReadyToWrite = YES;
}
```

logic method to stop recording:

```
-(void)logicMethodToStopRecording{
    
    float time = [self.timeFromServer floatValue];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, time * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self stopRecording];
    });
}
```

actual stop recording Method:

```
-(void)stopRecording{
    [self stopWritingToVideoFile];
}

-(void)stopWritingToVideoFile {
    [self.assetWriterMyData finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
        [self showLoading];
        if(!self.continueRunning){
            return;
        }
         [self sendVideo]; 
// sends video file referenced in startWritingToVideoFile method
        }];
    }
```

The sending video method:

```
-(void)sendVideo{
    [self.xxxxxx sendAPI:self.userToVerifyUserId videoPath:self.videoPath callback:^(NSString *jsonResponse){
        [self handleResponse:jsonResponse];
    }];
}
```

The response is handled by the following method:

```
-(void)handleResponse: (NSString*)result{
    
    [Utilities deleteFile:self.videoPath];
        
   //if no success but retry is true. re-record and re-send.
    if(!self.success && retry){
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self startRecording]; // start recording called again
        });
    }
```

The initial file I create has suppose **x seconds** of video ---- it is being generated correctly

However, during re-attempts:

I am deleting the old file and recreating new files. Still my video output in the second and third attempts have black screen for **n+x and 2n+x** times. Please help.

************** EDIT ****************************************************

Additionally the callback method for AVCaptureSession does the following:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    
        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        // a very dense way to keep track of the time at which this frame
        // occurs relative to the output stream, but it's just an example!
        static int64_t frameNumber = 0;
        if(self.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData){
            if(self.pixelBufferAdaptor != nil){
                [self.pixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:imageBuffer
                                      withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(frameNumber, 25)];
                frameNumber++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**************************EDIT - 2 *********************************************

```
+(NSString *)pathForTemporaryFileWithSuffix:(NSString *)suffix
{
    NSString *  result;
    CFUUIDRef   uuid;
    CFStringRef uuidStr;
    
    uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    assert(uuid != NULL);
    
    uuidStr = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
    assert(uuidStr != NULL);
    
    result = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", uuidStr, suffix]];
    assert(result != nil);
    
    CFRelease(uuidStr);
    CFRelease(uuid);
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi - just eyeballing the code .. can you also show ```Utilities pathForTemporaryFileWithSuffix:``` code?

Comment: There you go Sir added!

Comment: No sorry - I was thinking *maybe* the temp file has the same name each time and is not deleted or something like that. Small but probably irrelevant things are the ```sendVideo``` method you use but you posted code for ```sendPhoto``` and maybe when you delete the file in ```handleResonse``` also set ```readyToWrite``` to ```NO``` and a few others also (e.g. ```self.isRecording``` and friends) and maybe also ```self.videoPath``` to ```nil```.

Comment: Ooops! sendPhoto is actually sendVideo. Corrected.

Comment: Just fishing here - I looked at your code in detail but it seems fine as far as I can see, however, I think the issue is in the ```captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:``` message or in how it is called. The problem is to really go deeper I need to see how you message this and how the message parameters are initialised, and the code is already fairly dense. Anyhow, see what you can post along these lines as well. What I mean is how you message this and e.g. how you create and configure the e.g. ```captureOutput``` parameter to this message.